# TypeScript Interface Function Parameter-passing

Tags: typescript, function, interface, parameter-passing

The course indicates the code has error: Argument of type {"name":string} is not assignable to parameter of type 'squareDescriptor'. Property "size" is missing in type {"name":string;}.

Course link:https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV273x+1T2019/courseware/dbe869f1929d4e46b3b03e60361b9a24/54cf9872f47042b19caf02ab9eac548e/3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMicrosoft%2BDEV273x%2B1T2019%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4068996cfa8bb844ccaa4449cb0cbaead3

I tried the code and does not have the error.

```
interface squareDescriptor{
    "name":string,
    "size":number
}

let squareFn : Function = (square : squareDescriptor) => {
    return square.name;
}

let square = {
    "name": "a square"
}

let executeFn = squareFn(square);
```

expected: error

actual results: no error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Function` type just tells the compiler that it holds functions which you can pass any arguments to and may return some value. `squareFn` is a function of type `Function` so any arguments may be passed to it. The function you happened to assign to it accepts only a single `squareDescriptor` but that doesn't matter. The only type that matters is the type of the variable.

To get that error message, you'll have to change the declaration to not use `Function` but the actual type of the function you're assigning.  You could either omit the type, then the compiler will infer the correct type for you, or explicitly add the correct type.

```
let squareFn1 = (square : squareDescriptor) => {
    return square.name;
}
// or
let squareFn2 : (square : squareDescriptor) => string = (square : squareDescriptor) => {
    return square.name;
}
```